# How to save and delete calendar events using EventKit in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, eventkit

I'm pretty new to swift and I've been trying to create and delete calendar events using EventKit and EventKitUI and so far I've been able to **create** events, but I'm struggling to **delete** them. If you have any pointers please let me know! Here's the ViewController code I have so far:

```
import EventKit
import EventKitUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, EKEventViewDelegate {
    
    let store = EKEventStore()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(didTapAdd))

    }
    
    @objc func didTapAdd(){
        
        store.requestAccess(to: .event) {[weak self] success, error in
            if success, error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let store = self?.store else { return }
                    
                    // Describes the event to be added
                    let newEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
                    newEvent.title = "My Event"
                    newEvent.startDate = Date()
                    newEvent.endDate = Date()
                    
                    // Lets user edit the event themselves, we dont want this?
                    //let otherVC = EKEventEditViewController()
                    //otherVC.eventStore = store
                    //otherVC.event = newEvent
                    //self?.present(otherVC,
                                  //animated: true,
                                  //completion: nil)
                    
                    let vc = EKEventViewController()
                    vc.delegate = self
                    vc.event = newEvent
                    let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                    self?.present(navVc, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    func eventViewController(_ controller: EKEventViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventViewAction) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As vadian said try to only request access once a instance - it can make sense to check the access every time you open the app. You might not have the ability to change the access once it's removed, but you can tell the user why it's not working.

I have created two functions: Create event and delete event. Maybe you can use them:

```
var createdEvent: EKEvent?
func createCalendarEvent() {
        
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            if granted && error == nil {
                
                let event = EKEvent(eventStore: self.eventStore)
                event.title = "The guide worked "
                event.startDate = Date()
                event.endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(7200)
                
                event.notes = "Follow more guides on softwareanders.com and create more apps."
                
                
                event.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                
                
                do {
                    try self.eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                    
                    self.createdEvent = event
                } catch {
                    print("Error saving event: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Access to calendar not granted or an error occurred.")
            }
        }
    }


func deleteEventById(eventId: String) {
if let eventToDelete = eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventId) {
    do {
        try eventStore.remove(eventToDelete, span: .thisEvent)
    } catch {
        print("Error deleting event: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

}

If you want to read more about EventKit I have made a guide where you can create, delete, edit, fetch one and fetch all - [link here](https://softwareanders.com/swift-eventkit-calendar-management/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all perform `requestAccess` only **once** when launching the app.

Second of all in your code you create a new event but you don't save it in the store.

You have to call

```
try eventStore.save(newEvent, commit: true)
```

Deleting works very similar. You need the reference to the `EKEvent` instance then call

```
try eventStore.remove(event, commit: true)
```

To get the instance use [`predicateForEvents(withStart:end:calendars:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507479-predicateforevents) and [`events(matching:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507183-events)